# Machine-readable descriptions for popular REST APIs

Tags: web-services, rest, wadl

[Apigee seems to have](http://apigee.com/docs/console-go/content/set-apigee-api-console) a large collection of WADL files for their [console](https://apigee.com/console/). Is there any way to download those WADL files? Or does anybody know of another extensive collection of machine-readable Web service descriptions?

I'm sure you're going to tell me that the idea of WADL is not in the spirit of REST and I would agree. What I'm trying to do is to build a more or less generic crawler for popular REST APIs. But as long as most so-called REST APIs don't implement [HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) (i.e. there are no integrated links to further resources), it would be useful to have a WADL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the WADLs by using the below API:

```
https://api.apigee.com/v1/consoles/console_name/apidescription?format=wadl
```

For example if the Console's Url is https://apigee.com/console/**twitter**, then `console_name` = twitter.

The response of the API is the WADL itself. You can copy the contents of the respone into a .xml file and use it.

Hope this helps!